# Class not registered when running unit test but runs OK in debug

Tags: c#, unit-testing, com

When I run my application in debug mode it runs fine. When I run unit tests I get the following:

> Test method XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn.UnitTests.SolidWorksPartReferenceTest.CheckForGoodReference threw exception: 
>       System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00AB5D8D-2B8F-416B-9761-92FACC8872BE} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

This is the code that fails:

```
SwDMClassFactory swClassFact = default;
SwDMApplication4 swDocMgr = default;
SwDMDocument24 swDoc = default;
swClassFact = new SwDMClassFactory();  <---- Fails here
```

What would cause this?
How would I resolve?

Comment: Try a clean build  Check DateTime of exe in the project bin folder.  Check Debug and Release.  Usually issue like the exe you are using wasn't recompiled, or other project did not get recompiled.  Checking the timesptamp of the exe will verify the issue.  Yor main project could be release and other project could be debug.  And you are link to other project release and the debug got compiled and release did not get compiled.

Comment: Does Solid Works require some form of COM [license](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/219008) in order to operate?  If so, the license may not be copied to the [shadow] folders where the unit tests are run from?  Depending on your unit test framework and runner, they _may not run from the same location as they are built_ and _only immediate dependiences are copied from unit test execution folders_.  So you might have to specify additional dependencies

Comment: When you google the error message then you'll see there are only ever two reasons for this error.  One is that the component is not installed, you know that is not the case.  The other is that the bitness of the process is not correct.  You'll have to force it for the unit test runner, it is not obvious which one you use.